# Prove that a $f(c)=c$ given an interval where the function is continuous over

Tags: calculus, limits, functions, continuity

If $f(x)$ is continuous over the interval $[a,b]$ $a,b \in R$   $ a<b$ such that $f(a), f(b)$ also belong to the interval $[a,b]$

Prove that there exists some value $c$ in $[a,b]$ such that $f(c)=c$

I defined $g(x) = f(x) - x$

I know I should use the intermediate value theorem and demand $g(x) = 0$ but $0$ is not in the given interval, what I should to to solve this?

Thanks!

Comment: Note $g(a)\ge0$ and $g(b)\le0$. ($0$   being in $[a,b]$ or not doesn't matter.)

Comment: How can you tell that? I think that is enough to solve the problem, can you please elaborate ?:)

Comment: For the first assertion: $g(a)=f(a)-a$, and $a\le f(a) $ since $f(a)\in[a,b]$.

Answer (score 1):

From $g(x)=f(x)-x$, we deduce that $g$ is continuous on $[a,b]$. Moreover, we see that $g(a)=f(a)-a\ge 0$, $g(b)=f(b)-b\le 0$, and so $g(a).g(b)\le 0$. This implies that there exists a $c\in [a,b]$ such that $g(c)=0$, or $f(c)=c$.